# mxGraph js doesn't encode overlay with vertex

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

In mxGraph-js i use following code to add overlays to vertices.

```
graph.addCellOverlay(cell, overlay);
```

And encode graph to xml with

```
var graph = new mxGraph(container);
var xml = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
```

Then decode it back using following method.

```
var doc = mxUtils.parseXml(xml);
var codec = new mxCodec(doc);
codec.decode(doc.documentElement, graph.getModel());
```

My issue is when decoding the encoded graph back it draws the graph without overlays. It seems when encoding overlays doesn't get encoded into xml.
How can i encode graph with overlays and then decode it back properly ?.

Answer (score 0):

I have ran across the same issue. Without digging through the mxGraph js code I suspect it's a missing feature or possibly broken functionality.

Here are a few possible options that I see.

1. Embed image into cell style. *See source example fixedicon.html.*

   ```
   <mxGraphModel>
       <root>
           <mxCell id="0"/>
           <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
           <mxCell id="2" value="Fixed icon" style="shape=label;image=images/plus.png;imageWidth=16;imageHeight=16;spacingBottom=10;fillColor=#adc5ff;gradientColor=#7d85df;glass=1;rounded=1;shadow=1;" vertex="1" parent="1">
               <mxGeometry x="20" y="20" width="80" height="50" as="geometry"/>
           </mxCell>
       </root>
   </mxGraphModel>
   ```
2. Port type cells (defined in style) that are related via parent attribute to main cell. *See source example ports.html.*

   ```
   <mxGraphModel>
     <root>
       <mxCell id="0"/>
       <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
       <mxCell id="2" value="<h1 style="margin:0px;">Website</h1><br><img src="images/icons48/earth.png" width="48" height="48"><br>
           <a href="http://www.jgraph.com" target="_blank">Browse</a>" vertex="1" connectable="0" parent="1">
         <mxGeometry x="280" y="200" width="120" height="120" as="geometry">
           <mxRectangle width="120" height="40" as="alternateBounds"/>
         </mxGeometry>
       </mxCell>
       <mxCell id="3" value="Trigger" style="port;image=editors/images/overlays/flash.png;align=right;imageAlign=right;spacingRight=18" vertex="1" parent="2">
         <mxGeometry y="0.25" width="16" height="16" relative="1" as="geometry">
           <mxPoint x="-6" y="-8" as="offset"/>
         </mxGeometry>
       </mxCell>
       <mxCell id="4" value="Input" style="port;image=editors/images/overlays/check.png;align=right;imageAlign=right;spacingRight=18" vertex="1" parent="2">
         <mxGeometry y="0.75" width="16" height="16" relative="1" as="geometry">
           <mxPoint x="-6" y="-4" as="offset"/>
         </mxGeometry>
       </mxCell>
       <mxCell id="5" value="Error" style="port;image=editors/images/overlays/error.png;spacingLeft=18" vertex="1" parent="2">
         <mxGeometry x="1" y="0.25" width="16" height="16" relative="1" as="geometry">
           <mxPoint x="-8" y="-8" as="offset"/>
         </mxGeometry>
       </mxCell>
       <mxCell id="6" value="Result" style="port;image=editors/images/overlays/information.png;spacingLeft=18" vertex="1" parent="2">
         <mxGeometry x="1" y="0.75" width="16" height="16" relative="1" as="geometry">
           <mxPoint x="-8" y="-4" as="offset"/>
         </mxGeometry>
       </mxCell>
     </root>
   </mxGraphModel>
   ```
3. Shape cell and image cell grouped together.

   ```
   <mxGraphModel>
     <root>
       <mxCell id="0"/>
       <mxCell id="1" parent="0"/>
       <mxCell id="6" value="" style="group" parent="1" vertex="1" connectable="0">
         <mxGeometry x="70" y="70" width="120" height="85" as="geometry"/>
       </mxCell>
       <mxCell id="4" value="" style="shape=image;imageAspect=0;aspect=fixed;verticalLabelPosition=bottom;verticalAlign=top;image=images/close.png;" parent="6" vertex="1">
         <mxGeometry x="5" y="76" width="9" height="9" as="geometry"/>
       </mxCell>
       <UserObject label="shape" id="3">
         <mxCell style="whiteSpace=wrap;html=1;" parent="6" vertex="1">
           <mxGeometry width="120" height="60" as="geometry"/>
         </mxCell>
       </UserObject>
     </root>
   </mxGraphModel>
   ```

Comment: I am leaning towards option #2 as I need to assign click events to the images.

Answer (score 0):

Was exploring adding child cells as in option #2 from initial answer but found no way to add click event handlers. Ended up digging into source code and found that in the mxCellCodec class it instantiates an mxObjectCodec having a default exclusion list that included overlays.

```
var codec = new mxObjectCodec(new mxCell(),
['children', 'edges', 'overlays', 'mxTransient'],
['parent', 'source', 'target']);
```

Solution was to remove "overlays" from codec exclusion list. I also had to set the allowEval property to true to allow event listener functions to also be encoded & decoded.

```
// remove overlays from exclude list for mxCellCodec so that overlays are encoded into XML
var cellCodec = mxCodecRegistry.getCodec(mxCell);
var excludes = cellCodec.exclude;
excludes.splice(excludes.indexOf('overlays'), 1);

// set flag to allow expressions (function) to be encoded
cellCodec.allowEval = true;

// set flag to allow expressions (function) to be decoded
mxObjectCodec.allowEval = true;
```